Linux Mint 20.02 Cinnamon -- black screen on startup, no mouse showing
I moved my research computer (Linux Mint 20.02 Debbie Cinnamon OS) home, and booting it now, it allows me to select “LMDE 4 Debbie”, but after that the screen goes black, showing no mouse.
When I am on the page to select booting in recovery mode, and press "e" for options, these are the setparams shown:
setparams for recovery mode
This is what appears when I do boot in recovery mode:
booting in recovery mode
I tried the upvoted solution from the following link (adding "nomodeset" after "quiet splash"), but it appears to not have changed anything:
[url]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098505/linux-mint-18-3-black-screen-after-booting/58793928#58793928[/url]
What could be blocking the boot?

If this happens only at home it might be a network issue, requiring connectivity to boot. Contact IT where you were doing research for help on that; they likely have encountered this issue before.
